# Boolean Difference only cuts my main object, doesn't delete any vertices

Tags: modifiers

I've added a torus and and then a cylinder to the middle of it and tried to delete the cylinder from the torus, but instead of deleting the vertices within the cylinder object, it just makes a cut through the torus.

I've tried recalculating the normals of both objects to be outside and then inside (same for each). I've deleted loose vertices (there shouldn't have been any, but the torus had a few).

I tried triangulating the large faces on the top and bottom of the cylinder.

I've made sure the cylinder overlaps the torus in the z direction by a lot.

I haven't modified either object in any way other than through their numeric parameters (scale, dimensions, etc).

I've applied all transforms.

Any insight as to why these two basic meshes created by Blender itself won't boolean difference?

[image]

Comment: please provide blend file

Comment: by the way...is the cylinder closed? has it top and bottom face?

Comment: @Chris Yes, he tried triangulating the top and bottom faces to resolve the problem.

Comment: ähm...maybe i am too silly to understand...do you wanna do this? [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/0o83c.png ...just works ....but i think, i misunderstood...

Comment: @Chris I guess that's how it should be, but I actually had the same problem (in 2.83.5, but not in 2.92.0).

Comment: @GordonBrinkmann: thank you for your kind information

Comment: If you're going to stick with 2.8x rather than moving to 2.9x, you should at least move to 2.83, which is the version of 2.8x that is receiving long term support.

Comment: @MartyFouts But for this bug it won't help since my 2.83.5 LTS had it as well. Apart from that I agree with you.

Answer (score 2):

I've tried it with the default torus and default cylinder and got the same problem. I resolved this with several methods: moving the cylinder just a little off the center or scaling it up or down just a little. I guess the cylinder cuts exactly through the vertices of the torus and maybe Blender has some issues calculating it correctly. Also adding a *Subdivision Surface* modifier. Nearly everything helps except for keeping it at default.

EDIT: Well it doesn't cut exactly through the vertices becauses the objects have different resolutions. But still the edges overlap each other... I guess that's why. And just for clarification: I only have this problem in Blender 2.83.5, not in 2.92.0 or 2.93.0 Beta.

Comment: i don't understand !? make me intelligent! ;) isn't that what he wants? for me this works with default torus + cylinder: https://youtu.be/0SlPlVkTVz0

Comment: Maybe it is an older bug, I've added it in my answer that I can only reproduce it with 2.83.5 but not 2.92.0 (in his screenshot you see it's 2.81.16, so even older).

Comment: aaahhhh, ok thanks. I am not that silly, just a bit inattentive ;)

Comment: so once again (as usual and always) upvote from me ;) you deserve it